# query issue - grabbing dates 2 years > current date

Tags: sql-server, select

I have two tables in a database: 'Events' and 'Days'

Events table has these columns:

```
ID | Parent_ID
---------------
303|    4
304|   -1
305|    3
306|   -1
```

Days table has these columns:

```
Event_ID | Day
------------------------------------
303      |  2010-06-24 00:00:00.000
304      |  2013-08-21 00:00:00.000
305      |  2011-09-23 00:00:00.000
306      |  2011-12-04 00:00:00.000
303      |  2012-12-24 00:00:00.000
304      |  2010-11-06 00:00:00.000
305      |  2012-03-14 00:00:00.000
306      |  2011-06-12 00:00:00.000
305      |  2010-03-19 00:00:00.000
304      |  2009-01-20 00:00:00.000
```

What I'm trying to do is, in the Events table, find each ID who has a Parent_ID of -1, then find the same ID listed under Event_ID in the Days table, and return the last date entered IF it is greater than two years from the current date.

So for example, the query should grab 304 and 306 ID from the Events table since they both have -1 for the Parent_ID, and should return:

```
2013-08-21 00:00:00.000
```

and

```
2011-12-04 00:00:00.000
```

since they are the last entries for the two ID's that are greater than two years from the current date.

Not really sure how to do the greater than two years part. What I have tried is:

```
select max(day) as day
from Events e join Days d on d.Event_ID = e.ID
where e.Parent_ID = -1
```

this returns just the latest entry out of all the Event_IDs.

Comment: Google and learn about the DATEDIFF() and DATEADD() functions in SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following using `GROUP BY HAVING` and `DATEADD`

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0eb4c/1)

```
SELECT
  Event_ID,
  MAX(Day)
FROM Days
WHERE Event_ID IN (SELECT ID FROM Events WHERE Parent_ID = -1)
GROUP BY Event_ID
HAVING MAX(Day) < DATEADD(dd, -730, getdate())
```

Comment: This is close, except it's returning dates less than two years from the current date as well.

Comment: Looks like it works, I just had to change the > to < because it was giving me all dates less than two years from the current date. Thank you!

Comment: Corrected. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Just wondering, how does the "WHERE Event_ID IN" part work? I know it's comparing the Event_ID with ID from the Events table. But what does the "IN" do here?

Comment: It gets a list of id's where the parent_id is -1. I just did that instead of joining the tables.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for the dates that are 2 years older than current date (if not let me know so that I will update the answer)

```
where e.Parent_ID = -1 and d.Day < dateadd(day,-730,getdate())
```

Comment: This is correct, but only the LATEST date entry, for each ID who's parent_ID = -1. Your statement is just returning one entry.